# Алгоритм распределения записей в MySql для разных потоков

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица с большим количеством записей, например 20 млн.
В ней имеется поле `thread` типа `int`

Имеется программа которая установлена на 10-ти виртуальных машинах, которая обрабатывает эти записи, в каждой программе имеется номер в данном случае от 1 до 10, который указывает с какими записями работать, чтобы небыло конфликтов.

При начальном запуске, для примерно равномерного распределения записей я использовал такой запрос.

```
UPDATE accounts SET thread = (id % 10) + 1;
```

Но при добавлении новых записей в эту таблицу такой подход уже не работает, ибо программы все время работают да и произойдет рассинхронизация обработанных данных ибо (обработанные данные далее раскладываются по папкам с начальным названием совпадающим с номером потока).

Вопрос, как при добавлении новых записей в таблицу, их распределять равномерно по всем потокам?

> P.S. Есть вариант когда программа которая обработала запись с
> определенным номером потока, с этим же номером и добавляет новые
> записи, но этот вариант не подходит, если программа которая добавляет
> записи, не имеет номера и ничего об этом не знает.
>
> Транзакции применить нельзя...

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно почему все таки подход id%10 не приводит к желаемому результату. Во время работы программ происходит сильный перекос по загруженности очередей (из за разной скорости работы) и надо пытаться компенсировать этот перекос. И о какой рассинхронизации речь, ведь id даются подряд

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что при разном количестве записей в таблице, полю thread присвоятся одинаковые номера???

Comment: сами нет. я спрашиваю почему не подходит обычный остаток от деления, что не так в таблице ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое решение, это генерировать threadId при добавлении в базу, например с помощью тригера и в данном случае никакой рассинхронизации не будет (id же постоянный и выражение будет давать всегда однозначение в разные моменты времени) и выбирать по окончании обработки определенного количества записей, записи с threadId программы. У вас же выражение (id%10)+1, которое по сути является равномерным распределением 10 воркеров по всем записям.

Надеюсь, что у меня есть возможность **покритиковать** ваш подход. У вас есть проблема глубже и она состоит в нем. С этим подходом Вы столкнетесь со многими проблемами: привязанность к количеству воркеров, возможность зависания определенного воркера и его простаивание (ведь задача заранее привязана к нему, а уж как он будет работать неизвестно), необходимость привязывать воркера жестко каждый раз, создавать лишнюю нагрузку на базу на выборку необработанной записи.

Я бы предложил Вам использовать сервер очередей (например RabbitMq), у вас будет какой-то генератор, который будет добавлять задачи в эту очередь, и воркеры (ваши программы), которые соединяются к серверу очередей и получают задачи. Вам будет не важно, сколько у вас будет программ работать, какая из них зависнет - это все контролирует RabbitMq, а в добавок вы получите удобную статистику по обработке и повышенную отказоустойчивость. После выполнения задачи, воркер сообщает, что задача успешно завершена, удаляет ее из очереди и например отправляет отчет на какой-нибудь адрес.

Единственное, что в этом подходе нужно контролировать выгрузку задач в сервер очередей, а если важен только результат, то задачи можно напрямую складировать в RabbitMq, как например это делается с отправкой писем.